# Inline editing and Save datatable

Tags: save, datatables, inline-editing

I need to get inline editing in datatable columns and following is my code.

```
Contact.DataTable = $('#otable').DataTable( {
"ajax": {
                "url" : '/Contact/' + Contact.id,
                "dataSrc": function(json) {
                      return json.data;
                },
             },
            "responsive": true,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id"},
                { "data": "Course", "sClass": "course" },
                { "data": "Category", "sClass": "category" },
                { "data": "name" },
                {
                      "render": function ( data, type, method, meta ) {
                       return Contact.saveContact(method);
                    }
                },
            ]
        } );
```

I need to get inline editing for the fields

1. **Course**  - dropdown box showing as inline
2. **Category** - text field showing as inline

There will be a 'save' button each row - This will save the changes after editing dropdown and text.

Please help me to get inline editing and save without using editor plug-in.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Datatable columns inline edit - save new values on clicking button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005995/datatable-columns-inline-edit-save-new-values-on-clicking-button)

Comment: here I have an extra field - for inline editing - that must be a text box. And I was looking for any other method for implemeting inline editing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add datatable editable for your data table

```
            $("#table_id").dataTable({
              "order" : [],
               'columnDefs': [ {
                         'targets': [1,3], // column index (For which order by is not required)
                         'orderable': false, // set orderable false for selected columns
                   }],
              language: {
                  searchPlaceholder: "Search records"
              }
            });
             $('#table_id').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
          editor.inline(this);
      });
          });
```

Add dataTables editor cdn(given below) afteryour dataTable jquery cdn :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables.net-editor/2.1.0/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
```

Update your td tag of Editable column into below form

```html
<td>
 <label style="cursor:pointer" class="editable-label" data-id="@i.CategotyId" data-field="Title">
</label>
 <input type="text" class="editable-input" style="display: none;" />
</td>
```

Add below js

For allowing click to edit

```
    $('.editable-label').on('click', function () {
    var label = $(this);
    var input = label.next('.editable-input');

    label.hide();
    input.val(label.text()).show().focus();
});
```

For focus out and submiting data

```
$('.editable-input').on('blur', function () {
    var input = $(this);
    var label = input.prev('.editable-label');

    var newValue = input.val();
    label.text(newValue);
    input.hide();
    label.show();

    var Id= label.data('id');
    var field = label.data('field');

    console.log(field, storyId, newValue);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ControllerName/MethodName',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            Id: Id,
            columnName: field,
            columndata: newValue,
        },
        success: function (response) {

            alert("Updated");

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('An error occurred while deleting the data.');
        }
    })

});
```